# Appending elements into list in a specific way

Tags: python, list

I have a task where I have to get a specific list. The task is that I get an input of a string, that only contains digits from **0-9**. Now, we have to append those elements in a specific way. We need to **cut** the string, so that the groups are only 2 to 4 digits long. Groups should start with 0 only if they have to. Every string is 2 to 30 digits long.

I've managed to get the list where groups don't start with 0, but my groups are too big. This is where I am having trouble. How do I manage this groups that are only 2 to 4 digits long.

Some examples for input and output:

> **Input:** `01365400606`
>   My output: `[0, 1, ' ', 3, 6, ' ', 5, 4, ' ', 0, 0, 6, 0, 6]`
>   **Desired Output:** `[0, 1, ' ', 3, 6, ' ', 5, 4, 0, 0, ' ', 6, 0, 6]`

Example where group has to start with 0 because there are more than four times 0 appears.

> **Input:** `011000000011000100111111101011`
>   **Desired output:** `[0, 1, " ", 1, 0, 0, 0, " ", 0, 0, 0, 0, " ", 1, 1, 0, " ", 0, 0, " ", 1, 0, 0, 1, " ", 1, 1, 1, 1, " ", 1, 1, 0, " ", 1, 0, 1, 1]`

There are more correct solutions to each string, i.e. `01365400606`, can be cut in a more ways:

1. `0136 5400 606`
2. `01 36 5400 606`

**My code:**

```
def NumberCutter(number):
    count = 0
    numberList = []
    numberListSolution = []

    for e in number:
        e = int(e)
        numberList.append(e)       

    for e in numberList:
        count += 1
        numberListSolution.append(e)
        if count % 2 == 0 and e != 0:
            numberListSolution.append(" ")

    return numberListSolution
```

Comment: Why do you test for `count % 2 == 0`?

Comment: First thing I see is that you check for an even "count" number instead of checking if it is between 2 and 4. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Well I had an idea to go through every element in a list, and because every group has to be atleast 2 digits long, this way I get the groups of 2, and then I want to check the 3rd element, if it is a 0, go to 4th element, if it is still 0, then add these two zeroes to the previous 2 digits because that will be the biggest possible group of 4, but I'm failing to do this...

Comment: Can you please clarify because I don't understand what are considered "correct outputs".  Is `013, 654, 00, 606` equally as valid? What is the logic of the split?

Comment: The priority should be the length of the group and then groups starting with 0, because they HAVE to be between 2 and 4 digits long and they are ALLOWED to start with 0 but only if they HAVE to.

Comment: The requirements are still largely muddy to me.  So I'm *guessing* 3 digits are not valid, but what is the priority of the 2 and 4 digits? Likewise in what situation is defined as "HAVE TO" for 0-started digits? It might help to illustrate your question better to define these clearly, and list out *all* the correct outputs for `01365400606`.

Comment: There are 2 cases: The groups are 2 to 4 digits long (including 2,3,4) and they each group shouldn't start with 0, but if they have to, it is allowed. F.e. Input is only 00000000, now you can cut it like this 00 00 00 00, 000 000 00, 0000 0000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def NumberCutter(number):
    count = 0
    # use list comprehensive more readable than for loop
    numberList = [int(e) for e in number]
    numberListSolution = []

    def break_group():
        """ add space and return 0 to reset the count."""
        numberListSolution.append(' ')
        return 0

    # decision depends on the elements around current element we must know the index
    for i, e in enumerate(numberList):
        count += 1
        numberListSolution.append(e)

        if i == len(numberList) - 1:
            continue  # last element no need to add a space after it

        if count == 2:  # check for good decision when the count is two
            # if you want to short the group that start with 0 to the minimum uncomment this
            # but as you said priority to group length
            # try:
            #     # 0e1AA  == [0e 1AA] better than [0e1 AA]
            #     if not numberListSolution[-2] and numberList[i+1] and len(numberList) - i >= 2:
            #         numberListSolution.append(" ")
            #         count = 0
            # except IndexError:
            #     pass
            try:
                # Pe100 -->  Pe 100
                if numberList[i+1] and not numberList[i+2] and not numberList[i+3] and len(numberList) - (i + 1) == 3:
                    count = break_group()
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                # Pe101 -->  Pe 101
                if numberList[i+1] and not numberList[i+2] and numberList[i+3] and len(numberList) - (i + 1) == 3:
                    count = break_group()
            except IndexError:
                pass

        if count == 3:  # check for good decision when the count is three
            # if you want to short the group that start with 0 to the minimum uncomment this
            # but as you said priority to group length
            # try:
            #     # 0e1AA  == [0e 1AA] better than [0e1 AA]
            #     if not numberListSolution[-3] and numberList[i+1] and len(numberList) - i >= 2:
            #         numberListSolution.append(" ")
            #         count = 0
            #         continue
            # except IndexError:
            #     pass
            try:
                # PPeA1A --> PPeA 1A
                if numberList[i+2] and (len(numberList) - (i + 1) >= 2):
                    # priority to group length
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                # PP0111  PPe 111
                if not e and not numberList[i+1] and not numberList[i+2] and numberList[i+3]:
                    count = break_group()
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                # PPe1A...  PPE 1A....  at least there is two element after e and the first element is not zero
                # PPeAA] force PPE AA  there is exactly two element force the break
                if numberList[i + 1] and (len(numberList) - (i + 1) >= 2) or (len(numberList) - (i + 1) == 2):
                    count = break_group()
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                pass

        # we have 4 element force the group
        if count == 4:
            count = break_group()
            continue

    return numberListSolution

print(NumberCutter('011000000011000100111111101011'))
# [0, 1, 1, 0, ' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, ' ', 0, 0, 1, ' ', 1, 0, 0, 0, ' ', 1, 0, 0, 1, ' ', 1, 1, 1, 1, ' ', 1, 1, 0, ' ', 1, 0, 1, 1]
print(NumberCutter('01365400606'))
# [0, 1, 3, 6, ' ', 5, 4, 0, 0, ' ', 6, 0, 6]
```

**Note:**  in the comment I explained special cases to take a good decision with special letters:

- `P` is a previous number `>=0`
- `e` is the current element
- `A` is number after the e `>=0`
- when the `previous number (P)` or `Next number (A)` is no`Zero` I use `1`:  like `1Pe1A1`. and I use `0` for the inverse case `0PeA0AA`
- when `e` is `0` I use 0 like `P0A`

Comment: That's it, thanks! This was my plan the whole time but I didn't know about enumerate...

Comment: Why do we need statemein if count < 4, when you already have count == 2 and count == 3. those counts are already less than 4 big...

Comment: Actually I was testing and I changed the code a lot to match your requirements, and you can remove the if statement because it's always True, I didn't had the time to refactor the code more,  that if statement was before the first two if statements when I moved them to be handled first I disn't notice that it's always True,  just test it more and tell me where it doesn't give you the desired output

Comment: Hmm, I have 5 cases and they all work, why do you think somewhere it won't give me the desired output?

Comment: Because you gived two ouput of the same input I don't know If I understood your requirements correctly but I followed rules,  But i figured out that It's better to break a group that start with 0 as soon as there is a better sequence after it.

Comment: Yeah, there are more correct outputs to the same input, but your way works for that what I need

Comment: @RaZiiiGG indeed I forget some `continue` instruction in the code, I refactored the code to be more clear I think this version of code is much better the the previous one.